# Kendo Multiselect remove All option if no data is present

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendo multiselect dropdown which has a dataSource, I want to remove ALL(Select All) option from it if no data is returned from dataSource, what will be the best way to achieve it?

Comment: can you please share a minimum reproducible sample code?  multiselect or dropdown? They are 2 different elements

Comment: it is a multiselect used at https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/multiselect, only difference is that i have ALL option at first position which will select All of the elements, need to remove ALL when dataSource returns no data

Comment: How is the "All" button implemented? How is the DataSource update implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
var multiSelect= $("#multiSelect").kendoMultiSelect({
      dataBound: function(){ 
                var multiselect = $("#multiSelect").data("kendoMultiSelect");
                var items = multiselect.items().length;
                if(items < 2) {
                console.log("count elements",items);
                $(".k-item:first").hide();
                }
                },
...
});
```

In case the element count is less than 2 meaning only the All element is there you can remove it with **$(".k-item:first").hide();** or **$(".k-item:first").remove();**

Comment: suppose if i have filterable multi select then this will also remove the first record if filter returns only one row, can not hide just based on count only